# Why was my comment on free healthcare deleted twice?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I wrote a comment on this question

[Why do American people or politicians not complain about healthcare?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43178/why-do-american-people-or-politicians-not-complain-about-healthcare)

In which I only stated that "there is no such thing as free healthcare".

The first time I wrote it I gave some arguments on why this is true. It is basic economics and I was born in a country with the so called "free healthcare" so I have both theoretical and empiric knowledge on the matter. The comment was silently deleted despite it had some upvotes and the three remaining comments with the opposite statement remained.

I wrote the comment again, this time with less theory and it was immediately deleted again. This time I took a picture to verify it.

[image: proof]

And guess what? It magically disappeared again

[image: deleted]

The question is on hold so there is no point in answering.

I'm not accusing anybody but I have to ask. Do we have unchecked political bias on a site that, I think, should be based on freedom of expression. I'm new on the site and if this are the rules of the game I might as well use my time elsewhere.

PD: I'm saving the content of the question in case it is deleted. XD

Comment: I'm curious what country you are in where healthcare costs more than in the US, since the US spends the most, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_total_health_expenditure_per_capita

Comment: @Byran: Perhaps "cost" includes more than just financial expenses.

Comment: @BenVoigt I used "cost" as a shorthand for "financial expense": OP actually said "more expensive" and the chart I linked is "expenses"...

Comment: @BryanKrause: Well, outlawing medicine would certainly lower the financial expenses associated.  But that's not a cost I think we should pay.

Comment: @BenVoigt Who suggested outlawing medicine? devconcept said healthcare in their country (presumably govt-sponsored) was more expensive than in the US; that assertion makes little sense since the US is the most expensive, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Bryan: The USA is not the most expensive.  It spends the most, but that is not the same thing.  It's very possible that some procedures are more expensive for residents in devconcept's country.  Perhaps the procedure simply cannot be performed in-country, so the expense is international flights plus the cost of the procedure elsewhere.  Another procedure might involve bringing equipment and experts to the patient from another location.  The reason these don't result in higher overall spending is because people simply don't get the procedure done, while an America with the same diagnosis does.

Comment: It's even possible (although less likely), that *all* procedures are more expensive in devconcept's country... and that lower frequency completely accounts for lower spending.

Comment: @BenVoigt That would be interesting insight for OP to respond to my question, but I am not aware of any country where that is the case: support it with an example. For example, see https://www.healthsystemtracker.org/chart-collection/how-do-healthcare-prices-and-use-in-the-u-s-compare-to-other-countries/ - only colonoscopies are more expensive in the UK than the US, and the US is substantially more costly on every other measure than other countries.

Comment: @BenVoigt actually, in many unplanned cases getting healthcare in another EU country as an EU citizen covered via another EU country's system it will be reimbursed so it does show up in the country where one is covered ([source](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/unplanned-healthcare/payments-reimbursements/index_en.htm)). In the example you give where it's needed to go abroad, that's often covered as well, see [this](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/planned-healthcare/expenses-reimbursements/index_en.htm).

Comment: @BryanKrause: Yeah, UK isn't going to set any records for expense.  I'm thinking the prize for "most expensive" on a per-equivalent-procedure basis is likely to go to somewhere near the Persian Gulf, because [the royal families are (in)famous for engaging in "medical tourism"](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-saudi-king/saudi-king-to-seek-medical-treatment-in-u-s-idUSTRE6AK0X620101121) (cost = travel + cost in US of lavish private physician) and the same care isn't available to the general population, so there are no people receiving the procedure inexpensively to bring the average down.

Comment: @BryanKrause "The US spends the most" That is precisely what is wrong with your assumption. Healthcare cost, when you are trying to figure out if you can make it "free", cannot be measured on country expense but in personal cost. How much tax I will have to pay now to "make it free". The state doesn't go to the doctor so politicians will be in favor if they get more votes despite the economy going to ruin (which is what you'll likely get). The factors to consider are 1. income percent going to healthcare as taxes and 2. quality of the service you get in a state run scheme (very low)

Comment: @devconcept You didn't answer my question. The US, despite spending more than other countries, is not anywhere close to having the best health outcomes. Many places with govt-sponsored healthcare have less costs and better outcomes. Clearly the private system does not produce the best care. The quality of the service in the US is unfortunately quite low compared to how much it costs.

Comment: @BryanKrause What you are doing is the classic bias that if something is for profit it is worse than if is govt-run. Ask yourself this. If US healthcare with the incentives of profit is not really that good what makes you think that making the government (which by definition is more corrupt and incompetent because is run by politicians) will be better? You spend more because you have better life standards than other countries. I live in Cuba, where you get 95% of your salary removed to pay education and health and then you can get them "for free" with the worst possible quality.

Comment: @devconcept I am not assuming that for profit is worse. I am only comparing the US system to others like in Europe which have a similar cost of living. There is no incentive for profit in delivering good care in the US, only incentive for insurance companies to make as much profit as possible, which means paying doctors less and charging customers more: it is not based on outcomes.

Comment: @BryanKrause Government intervention will only make it worse. Profit is always an incentive even in govt schemes because doctors will not work for free. They are not slaves. Do the math yourself, add the current income of private companies on top of the current govt expenditure and figure out how much this will increase taxes. I can tell you without any math, "a lot". Finally, do not fall in the naive thinking that relocating this expenses to the state will diminish the cost because every time this experiment is run you get the opposite effect, expenses always increase.

Comment: @devconcept Given that other countries have government sponsored healthcare and get better outcome for less cost, I don't see the evidence that government intervention will only make it worse. And yes, it will add to taxes, but it will also reduce private healthcare expenditures. If I pay $5000 more taxes and pay $1000 less in premiums plus my employer saves $5000 on my health plan that they can now pay in salary, I come out ahead.

Comment: @BryanKrause You are **assuming a lot**, the exactly same trap that most people that ask for socialism do, and then when the reality does not go as they planned they just give more money and power to the state assuming again that "this time" the problem will be solved. No, it will not. You can make a better system as long as the state does not intervene. My country is the living proof that you are trying to solve the problem with the worst possible solution. No wonder Bernie Sanders is the one asking for this. Maybe the Venezuelan model he praises so much is what you need in the US XD

Comment: I mean, there's no assumption here at all that public single-payer healthcare is cheaper for better; that's literally what the facts of the comparison are. You can whinge about "falling into the trap" or "when reality does not go according to plan" and claim that a state-run healthcare system won't improve anything, but you are simply arguing against the reality that exists now, plan or not.

Comment: @Nij And what are "the facts" of the comparison? The fact that you ignore the testimony of someone who actually lives in a country with "free healthcare"? The fact that your money in that scheme is now diluted into politicians and bureaucrats on top of the medicine, doctors and hospital expenses? The ridiculous idea than a bureaucrat can run a hospital better than a private company when the evidence continuously prove otherwise? Note that I'm not against having public healthcare but against "free healthcare" that means healthcare payed with your taxes fully controlled by the state.

Comment: Anecdotes are the lowest form of evidence, and worthless when better objective quantitative evidence exists. Speaking as someone who lives in a country with public single-payer healthcare, I'm absolutely sure I'd never live in the USA, to pay more for a worse job done. That's not a decision based on any testimony; it's because that is what the facts tell me would occur. Your comments verge on the ridiculous; you have yet to address these facts and instead provide only repeated sloganeering about socialists and red-herring comparison of the sociological atmosphere of Cuba to the USA and Europe.

Comment: @Nij By better quantitative evidence you mean the "nordic countries" who are [not socialist](https://www.thelocal.dk/20151101/danish-pm-in-us-denmark-is-not-socialist) and were richer before they implanted "free healthcare" supported by [huge taxes](https://youtu.be/MgrJnXZ_WGo?t=573), all of this explained by themselves. Just because you live in a scheme where you get the most and pay very little it [doesn't mean that you can force everyone else to blindly adopt your model](https://www.nationalreview.com/2019/05/nordic-countries-scale-back-welfare-states/). Someone will have to pay for you.

Comment: So your argument boils down to being selfish, even though that makes you personally worse off, because something something government is evil god bless the free market.

Comment: @Nij Please do not play the moral high-ground card with me. Spending someone else money is not exactly being benevolent. It boils down to the fact that this must be an informed decision instead of advertising it as "free" which is a huge lie. You must say that they will have less money because of the huge tax increase(which could be saved by themselves);that some of that money will be spent on bureaucrats and that the only cases this actually worked were on tiny countries, for a small period of time and as long as the social contract was respected. The US doesn't fit in that description.

Comment: That "huge tax increase" replaces the money spent on insurance and the care itself, leaving individuals in largely the same position with most being better off, something you flatly ignore in your diatribe. Clearly you've decided that no possible evidence could support public single-payer healthcare because you first reject all evidence and the second imply that even if it were better, you'd refuse it because it involved the government. There remains no point in continued discussion.

Comment: @Nij The difference is that **you can choose** how to spend your money. You don't end up in the same position because with the state run scheme you need to pay bureaucrats and politicians on top of the total cost. I've decided that my evidence is the word of the prime minister himself which talks about this as a "catch". I agree there is no point in arguing because to continue it you should study some economics first and also inform yourself on how this policies almost ruined those countries.

Comment: You probably won't accept it, but private healthcare literally makes their money on waste. Insurance companies literally make money by taking more money in than it pays out. Some 30% of healthcare costs in the US are wasted on administrative costs managing the fragmented mess that is private insurgence, doubling that of the systems in UK and Canada. Maybe you want to spend more money for healthcare for some idealistic reasons, but don't expect everyone else to.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara What I'm arguing here is not whether public healthcare is better or worse in some particular scenario, what I'm saying is that 100% state owned healthcare advertised as "free" at the cost of a huge tax increase has more probability to be worse or at least the same than you current scheme. Read the statistics yourself "58% of US community hospitals are non-profit, 21% are government owned, and 21% are for-profit". Healthcare coverage is provided through a combination of private health insurance and public health coverage. You already have a lot of public healthcare in place.

Comment: It amuses me how you managed to say both of these things in the same sentence: *"What **I'm arguing here is not whether public healthcare is better or worse** in some particular scenario, what I'm saying is that 100% state owned healthcare advertised as "free" at the cost of a huge tax increase has more probability to be **worse or at least the same than you current scheme.**"*

Comment: Also, when you quote things, you really should cite them. As presented, those are not meaningful statistics to the topic at hand.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Well, when you have a 100% public healthcare and both of your kids almost die due to negligence because in a public healthcare system you are just a number you have to be suspicions of those kind of **political ads** designed to gain votes. You can find a scheme with public healthcare that works for you, create a safety net for the most needed without removing the choices from whole public. There is no need to be tyrannical. You could find those [statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_care_in_the_United_States) yourself if you even bother to look.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Because the highest probability is that they are worse and even when they are the same those numbers will not improve. They will only get worse as it happened in the Nordic countries.

Comment: @devconcept People die from negligence in private healthcare all the time too. By your reasoning, private healthcare must be evil too. You've made it clear your position is one of emotion, not reason. For that reason, I must conclude I cannot reason you out of your position, because reason did not get you into that position.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You are just another guy that needs to study [economics of healthcare](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/mankiw/files/economics_of_healthcare.pdf) "Defenders of the U.S. healthcare system accept that some reforms might  reduce costs, but they believe that reliable conclusions are hard to draw from the inter-national comparisons." Simply put you think that I'm ideologically corrupted because I stated a fact and what I'm against is not reform but political manipulation. Fun fact: That was also Castro's argument when someone didn't agree with him.

Comment: Casto! I just got capitalism good, socialism bad talkingpoints Bingo!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As shown in your screenshot, the question specifically refers to free healthcare as

> "health for free" from payed [sic] taxes

In other words, OP **already knows** that "free healthcare" is not actually free - especially since their profile indicates that they're from Spain, which *also* has "free" universal healthcare. So your comment was probably deleted as "not needed", which is a valid reason for deleting comments here on StackExchange. It happens all the time, and I hope you don't take it personally and continue to contribute here.

Comment: This makes sense... Also please forgive my sense of humor on the question XD

Comment: I see no evidence that the person asking the question on the main site "already knows that *free healthcare* is not actually free"... because that would provide an obvious answer to the question they ask of "Why do some people in the USA not complain?", the evidence that they asked the question anyway is that they didn't think about this aspect.

Answer (score 4):

Your comment was flagged and subsequent deleted twice because it did not fulfill any of the purposes comments should have according to the [help center article about the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). It did not request clarification from the author, did not provide constructive criticism aimed at improving the question and did not point out any transient meta-information.

Comment: The first line of the question says this "I am really amazed that in the USA you must pay for healthcare but people do not protest". Maybe in the USA some people know "there is no free healthcare" and this is why this is not a big deal. I think this could be relevant and it could actually lead to an answer, quoting: "Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post". How is a comment like this irrelevant?